# Typed $ rails server and output looks like it is stuck

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am doing Michael Hartl's Ruby and Rails Tutorial and am just getting started on my first app. I Typed `$ rails server` into the command line and got the following output:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.8 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2012-10-30 20:56:51] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-10-30 20:56:51] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-10-12) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
[2012-10-30 20:56:51] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2205 port=3000


Started GET "/assets/rails.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-30 20:57:56 -0400
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Served asset /rails.png - 200 OK (3ms)
```

It looks like this is still running and is stuck. The next step in the tutorial asks to add the new rails project to Git (after you've set up Git) via `$ git add`.  Should I do this in a new terminal window while the `$ rails server` still runs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, that will appear "stuck" while the server is running. You'll need to do any further commands in a new window. This is necessary for your app to display.